# Facebook graphAPI get id of friend posts with python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using python facebook-sdk (modified example code) to get feed from my facebook wall. That means my posts and my friends' posts. My scripts works just fine until there is more then 2 friend's posts - facebook starts grouping those posts and I can no longer get that post's ID - only of the first one.

This is what I mean by "grouped posts":
[fb grouped wall posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVd0V.png)

Here is my code:

```
import facebook
import requests


def get_it(post):

    print(post['message'])
    print(post)

access_token = '<mytoken>'
user = 'me'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

posts = graph.get_connections(user, 'feed', limit=20)
print(posts) 

while True:
    try:
        [get_it(post=post) for post in posts['data']]

        posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
    except KeyError:
        break
```

Now the prints give me successful results if there isn't more than 2 friend's posts and they aren't grouped.
the  dict looks like this
print(posts):

```
 {'paging': {'previous': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/XXX&access_token=XXX&__paging_token=XXX&__previous=1', 'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/XXX/feed?limit=20&access_token=XXX&__paging_token=XXX'}, 'data': [{'id': 'XXXXXX_XXXX', 'created_time': '2016-03-31T23:58:41+0000', 'message': 'test'}, {'id': 'XXX_XXX', 'created_time': '2016-03-31T23:33:43+0000', 'message': 'hehe'}]}
```

And everything goes fine, I can use the post IDs for the get_it method.

However, once there are more then 2 friend's posts, it gets grouped and suddenly
a new thing 'story' appears in the dict:

```
'data': [{'created_time': '2016-04-01T02:32:37+0000', 'story': 'XXX wrote on your Timeline.', 'id': '123_456'}, {'created_time': '2016-03-31T23:58:41+0000', 'message': 'test', 'id': '6666_6666'}
```

The 'story' ID works only for the LAST comment made in grouped wall posts.

Additionally, the next dict fields for some reason don't get passed in the get_it() method and print(post['message']) and print(post) return blank results.

How to solve this, so I get IDs and messages of all friends' posts on my wall as well as mine, please? I am really lost, tried everything. Thank you.

Comment: This is intended behavior and there are no plans to modify this aggregation feature to return all posts once aggregation happens.

Answer (score 0):

This was an intentional update by facebook to stop automating scripts and spamming.

It will not be rolled back unfortunately.